# Delphi: Incompatible types: 'Integer' and 'Extended' when both values are assigned as real

Tags: delphi

I'm trying to compile a rather basic program to calculate BMI however i seem to keep getting this error and I am not sure why or how to fix it.

these are my variables:

```
weight : real;
height : real;
bmi : real;
```

my coding is as follows:

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  weight := strtofloat(inputbox('weight', 'Enter your weight in        kilograms',''));
  height := strtofloat(inputbox('height', 'Enter your height in    centimeters',''));
  bmi := weight/sqr(height);
  EDIT1.Text := floattostr(BMI);
end;
```

How can I fix this error, and what is causing it?

Answer (score 7):

`Height` is being mistaken as `Self.Height`, which refers to the form's Height property, which is an integer. Use a different name for the variable, or make it local in scope to the method. The following works just fine for me:

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  Weight, Height, BMI: Real;
  s: string;
begin
  s := InputBox('Weight', 'Enter your weight in kilos', '');
  Weight := StrToFloat(s);
  s := InputBox('Height', 'Enter your height in centimeters', '');
  Height := StrToFloat(s);
  BMI := Weight/sqr(Height);
  Edit1.Text := FloatToStr(BMI);
end;
```

My preferred solution would be to use a different name, to avoid any possible confusion in the future. I'd probably do something more like this:

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  BodyWeight, BodyHeight, BMI: Real;
  s: string;
begin
  s := InputBox('Weight', 'Enter your weight in kilos', '');
  BodyWeight := StrToFloat(s);
  s := InputBox('Height', 'Enter your height in centimeters', '');
  BodyHeight := StrToFloat(s);
  BMI := BodyWeight/sqr(BodyHeight);
  Edit1.Text := FloatToStr(BMI);
end;
```

Comment: Thanks for that solution. At the time of programming this I didn't think about the variable name causing the problem due to the error message saying: "Incompatible types: 'Integer' and 'Extended' when both values are assigned as real" but Thanks for your help. I will that in mind when programming.

Comment: For the full coverage of the possible ways out - there are also a third option - to scope the global variable with the unit name, like `BMI := Weight/sqr(Unit1.Height);` - and a fourth option - making those variables members of TForm1 class. However in this specific case the variables by their nature are temporary ones and local-vars (#1 method) is the correct ways to design the program.